# Customising a plugin for Genesis/Studiopress Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, carousel, genesis

I have created a carousel (not perfect yet - images are not showing but it could work) with custom control icons ("next" "back") with Boostrap:http://homepage160630-v3.bitballoon.com/travel

Being not familiar with PHP, I found it difficult to integrate a CMS like Wordpress into my code, so I am trying to re-create the same site as a Genesis/Studiopress Wordpress site based on the Genesis Sample theme:
http://paulheartfieldphotography.com/home/portraits/

My biggest problem is to create the carousel. I have looked at "Easing Slider" plugin: of course it does not allow to position the control icons or even to create my own. 
I wonder what shall I do? try to create the custom carousel by transforming my Bootstrap code into PHP or try to edit the plugin? or something else?
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/easing-slider/

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to get bootstrap shortcode plugin like this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/bootstrap-3-shortcodes/

However there are a bunch of them and you should check what works best for you. The link above is just to visualize.